# Backprojection of a line to a plane

Tags: geometry

In the book below, it says the backprojection of a line is a plane via

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\pi}=\mathrm{P}^{\top} \mathbf{l}
\end{equation}

[equation from multiple view geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmbD5.png)

But shouldn't this be

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\pi}=\mathrm{P}^{+} \mathbf{l}
\end{equation}

where $\mathrm{P}^{+}$ is the pseudo inverse of $\mathrm{P}$?

Comment: In short, no, for the same reasons that under the point transformation $x\mapsto Mx$, lines transform as $l\mapsto M^{-T}l$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! But from https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/computervision/ECE661Folder/Lecture17.pdf a point x in 2D backprojects to \begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{X}=\mathrm{P}^{+} \mathbf{x}
\end{equation}

Comment: And an inverse transpose of $P^+$ is...?

Comment: Hi, I still don't get it, on slide 17-5 of https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/computervision/ECE661Folder/Lecture17.pdf, \begin{equation}
P^{+}=P^{T}\left(P P^{T}\right)^{-1}
\end{equation}. Do you mean the inverse transpose of this? How to compute the inverse of $P^{T}\left(P P^{T}\right)^{-1}$? Btw P is 3x4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preimage of a line $\mathbf l$ is the set of points $\mathbf X$ in the scene such that $\mathbf l^T(\mathtt P\mathbf X)=0$. However, $$\mathbf l^T(\mathtt P\mathbf X) = (\mathbf l^T\mathtt P)\mathbf X = (\mathtt P^T\mathbf l)^T\mathbf X$$ therefore the preimage of $\mathbf l$ is the plane $\mathbf\pi=\mathtt P^T\mathbf l$.

This parallels the manipulation commonly used to demonstrate that the image of a line $\mathbf l$ under the point transformation $\mathbf x'=\mathtt M\mathbf x$ is $\mathtt M^{-T}$, i.e., that lines are transformed by the inverse transpose of $\mathtt M$: $$\mathbf l^T\mathbf x = \mathbf l^T(\mathtt M^{-1}\mathbf x') = (\mathbf l^T\mathtt M^{-1})\mathbf x' = (\mathtt M^{-T}\mathbf l)^T\mathbf x'.$$ In a similar way, if image points are back-mapped via $\mathtt P^+$, then lines are, at least conceptually, back-mapped by its inverse transpose. Recall that $\mathtt P\mathtt P^+=\mathtt I$, so in this context $\mathtt P$ plays the role of the inverse transformation to $\mathtt P^+$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think you are right, but P here is 4x4 for P^-T to be valid. In my original question I thought P is 3x4.

Comment: @sholmes Yes, I was a bit hasty. See update.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation!