# How to project an ellipsoid to conic

Tags: geometry

In the book multiple view geometry, the perspective projection of an ellipsoid (dual form) to a conic is defined as

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{C}^{*}=\mathrm{PQ}^{*} \mathrm{P}^{\top}
\end{equation}

[equation from multiple view geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmbD5.png)

But shouldn't this be

\begin{equation}
\pi^{\top} Q^{*} \pi=\left(P^{+} \ell\right)^{\top} Q^{*}\left(P^{+} \ell\right) 
=
l^{\top} P^{+\top} Q^{*} P^{+} \ell
\end{equation}
$\mathrm{P}^{+}$ is the pseudo inverse of $\mathrm{P}$

so that when we substitute $\mathrm{C}^{*}=P^{+\top} Q^{*} P^{+}, l^\top C^* l = 0$, we get back $\pi^{\top} Q^{*} \pi=0$?

The rationale is that not every plane tangent to an ellipsoid will project to a line tangent to the conic, but every line tangent to the conic will project back to a plane tangent to the ellipsoid.

If we use the original definition in the book, then we get $(P \pi)^\top C^* (P \pi) = \pi^\top P^\top P Q^* P^\top P \pi$, which may not be zero.

This question is related to my previous question [Backprojection of a line to a plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3223788/673449)

Comment: This isn’t the projection of an ellipsoid. It’s the _outline_ of the projection.

Comment: It appears that, despite having accepted an answer to your previous question, you’re right back to believing that the back-projection of the line $\mathcal l$ is $P^+\mathcal l$ instead of $P^T\mathcal l$.

Comment: That wasn’t sarcasm; it was fact. You’re still getting these mappings backwards. The vectors that represent lines and planes are _covariant_: they do not transform in the same way as do coordinate vectors that represent points. If a _point_ transformation is represented by the matrix $P$, then neither $P\mathbf\pi$ nor $P^+\mathcal l$ really makes sense.

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood you, sorry, I finally see what you are saying now.

Comment: I can write up an answer for you, if you like, but I suspect that you can answer this one yourself now.